# What is the time limit for Fajr prayer?

Tags: prayer-timings

Assalamualaykum,

I actually want to know that what is the time limit for fajr prayer? When does it end? Some people says that the time is extended till 12:00 pm. So I do want to be sure about that. If I miss any prayer before sunrise and want to pray befor 12:00pm, will I do the niyat as kaza or not?

Jazakallah Khair

Comment: What prayer are you asking about?  Different times for different regions.

Comment: @Sayyid brother, I'm asking about Fazar prayer at morning..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Walecumsalam,

The time for Fajr (first prayer of the day in early morning) is till the sunrise. So you have to check exact time for sunrise in your area, and pray before it, but it is highly recommended to pray at first time.

Proven from this hadith:

> It was narrated from Abdullah bin Amr (RA) that the Prophet (PBUH)
>   said, “The time for Zuhr is so long as Asr has not come. The time for
>   Asr is so long as the sun has not turned yellow. The time for Maghrib
>   is so long as the twilight has not disappeared. The time for Isha is
>   so long as half of the night has not passed. The time for Fajr is so
>   long as the sun has not risen.” (Hadith No. 1386 (612), Book of
>   Masjids & Places of Prayer, Sahih Muslim, Vol. 2).

Also, in case you kept sleeping,then according to one hadith (i dont have it with me now) the time for prayer is, when you wake up (means, as soon as you wake up, and the time of prayer is gone,then pray as soon as you wake up.

Hope that answers the question

Comment: Make sure that time as soon as you wake up, is not between when the sun is still rising.. I mean it is OK to pray, after it has completely risen.

Comment: Okay, then I will have to be honest to myself not to escape the exact time, but as mentioned if I do it after the rising of the sun, then should I pray the fajr as kaza or as well..?

Comment: actually, there is nothing like Qaza in islam, when time for prayer is gone, then you have to make it up as soon as possible. but Never leave a single pray, ever. as leaving one prayer is a kufr according to many scholars.

Comment: @HamzaIslam brother, Thanks a lot! I didn't know that there in nothing like Qaza.. Jazakallah Khair.

Comment: @NadiaAli the thing is when salah not offered in it's stated fixed time becomes Qaza. But there is no special difference in the way of offering Qaza, you would offer it the same way you do it for normal Salah.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Its helpful.  Jazakallah Khair..